# In TSQL Can I/How can I fill an array with data from a table?

Tags: arrays, t-sql, while-loop

Here is the code I have so far. (I changed the column names and other stuff for safety)

```
/* declare empty array */
DECLARE @oArray varchar(26)
/* loop variables */
DECLARE @Counter INT
DECLARE @rows INT 
SET @Counter = 1
SET @rows    = (select count(z) from z where z like 'z-%' and z = 1)
/* fill array */
WHILE (@Counter <= @rows)
BEGIN
SET @oArray(@Counter) = (SELECT z FROM (
                         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY z ASC) AS RowNumber,*
                         FROM z WHERE z like 'z-%' and z = 1) AS taboo
                         WHERE RowNumber = @Counter)
END
```

It works up to the set in the while loop. Is there a way to perform something like this in TSQL? I tried to research this. However, I cannot seem to find any post like it. (for TSQL)

I need the @Counter to work at "@oArray(@Counter) = " & "WHERE RowNumber = @Counter".

I want to dynamically pull data from a particular table to be used in calculations without hardcoding in values.

Comment: This is going to be much more understandable if you provide your table schema, sample source data and sample results.  Whenever you talk about loops in a relational database context nearly every time the answer is to not use a loop because it can be done in a set operation.  My thought is that is certainly going to be the case here.

Comment: Please provide queries to create the table and insert some sample data for the sake of the discussion and in order to reproduce the scenario. In addition please explain what is the expected result according to the sample data.

Comment: This looks like an RBAR party - a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will go a long way.